# Redirect without needing to disable popups

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup, popup-window

I am looking for direction on how to redirect users to an external URL without them having to have their popups disabled.  Below is my current code:

```
            if (feeDue == '50.00') {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            window.open(redirectURL, '_self');
            urlEvent.fire();   }} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked when without the redirection popup when I did it in Production.  Was only a problem in Sandbox.